# Devise Returning 401 When Logging in Using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following, rather trivial, code that should log a user into my application using Devise. This actually works just fine if it's done using an HTML request rather than XHR. When I do it this way, the XHR is made,

```
          = form_for(@user, :url => session_path(@user), :remote => true) do |f|
            = f.label :email
            = f.text_field :email, :size => 15, :maxlength => 32
            = f.label :password
            = f.password_field :password, :size => 15, :maxlength => 32
            %br
            = f.submit "Sign in"
```

and the result is:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-04 13:24:44 -0800
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/_hello_page.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 16.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-04 13:24:54 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1cGaycA20NMhK0fOwQyN8e3aSFwCHB6BZcLwmvKTI3U=", "user"=>{"email"=>"obscured@someplace.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template devise/sessions/create, devise/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/sxross/Developer/iPhoneApps/motion/whos_here/whos_here_server/app/views"
  * "/Users/sxross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@whos_here_server/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
):
```

Everything is exactly as I expect it and it's clear that `Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JS` is telling the receiving controller "ship me back the JSON I want." So the question is why is the Devise controller trying to render a template instead of JSON and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at this?  http://jessehowarth.com/devise

Comment: Yeah. I did. I'm not sure what the magic was, but when I used jQuery.ajax with the proper accept-type and all, I was able to get my 200 return code. I won't answer this because I don't have the real "answer" to this. It just seems it should be easier. Thanks for the recommend, though!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a create.js.[erb|haml] file in views/devise/sessions

When you send a remote request for login, the request is done by Devise::SessionsController#create, and if you don't override it

```
respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
```

will look for a create.js.erb.
I ussualy just have

```
window.location = "<%= root_url %>"
```

in it.

Also, you would need to set

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :js]
```

inside config/initializers/devise.rb for this to work.

I for my own case have overridden the sessions controller with this:

```
@resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "sessions#failure")
sign_in(resource_name, @resource)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { respond_with @resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(@resource) }
  format.js
end
```

which throws me to a failure method if the authentication has failed, and process it in failure.js.erb to show the user that